# Очистка кэша в приложении

Tags: android, кэширование

Всем привет! Скажите, пожалуйста, кто знает чистится ли кэш приложения автоматически системой??? Просто я знаю что допустим когда в системе нет памяти для того чтобы отдать её другому приложению, то система начинает убивать фоновые активности и т.д. И вот у меня возник вопрос: чистится ли подобным образом кэш приложения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть `cacheDir` которые могут быть очищены системой, и есть неизменяемые

первый случай -

**getCacheDir ()**
  Returns the absolute path to the application specific cache directory on the filesystem. **These files will be ones that get deleted first when the device runs low on storage**. There is no guarantee when these files will be deleted. Note: you should not rely on the system deleting these files for you; you should always have a reasonable maximum, such as 1 MB, for the amount of space you consume with cache files, and prune those files when exceeding that space.

---

и неизменяемый cache -

**public File getExternalCacheDir ()
Added in API level 8**
Returns the absolute path to the directory on the external filesystem (that is somewhere on Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() where the application can place cache files it owns.

**This is like getCacheDir() in that these files will be deleted when the application is uninstalled, however there are some important differences:**

The platform does not always monitor the space available in external storage, and thus may not automatically delete these files. Currently the only time files here will be deleted by the platform is when running on JELLY_BEAN_MR1 or later and Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated() returns true. Note that you should be managing the maximum space you will use for these anyway, just like with getCacheDir().
External files are not always available: they will disappear if the user mounts the external storage on a computer or removes it. See the APIs on Environment for information in the storage state.
There is no security enforced with these files. All applications can read and write files placed here.
On devices with multiple users (as described by UserManager), each user has their own isolated external storage. Applications only have access to the external storage for the user they're running as.

**Writing to this path requires the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.**

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что нет.

Во первых, это было бы уже вредительство. Во вторых, на старом телефоне я доходил до ситуации, когда уже не хватает памяти. И никто не чистил кеш. Только выводилось сообщение о том, что памяти маловато.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Логично, я тоже так думаю, просто всё равно хотел убедиться.

Comment: Мне кажется, что не совсем так. Посмотрите API связанное с файлами. Там есть момент, что если файлы создаются с getCacheDir(), то система не гарантирует их сохранности. Вот ссылка: [public abstract File getCacheDir ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir())